ItemResponse attachment causing Reference Error
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but my best guess is that I'm handling the attachment wrong (although it only comes through as an ID and I append that too https://drive.google.com/open?id=ID_HERE). I have a Google Form where the only question is an attachment. Everything works fine when an attachment is added but when it's not I get the following error:

ReferenceError: attachment is not defined
at eval([unknown file]:8:60)
at eval([unknown file]:14:3)
at myFunction(Code:21:22)

I've tried declaring attachment independently and get the same error
Here is my gs and hmtl files
Code.gs
function myFunction(e) {
  var formResponses = e.response,
    itemResponses = formResponses.getItemResponses();
  var attachment = "",
    template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index"),
    message = "";

  for (x = 0; x < itemResponses.length; x++) {
    if (itemResponses[x].getItem().getTitle() === "Attachment") {
      if (itemResponses[x].getResponse() === undefined) {
        attachment = "No file was attached";
        template.attachment = attachment;
      }
      else {
        Logger.log("Made it here");
        attachment = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + itemResponses[x].getResponse();
        template.attachment = attachment;
      }
    }
  }
  message = template.evaluate().getContent();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(EMAIL, 'SUBJECT', 'This email contains html', {htmlBody: message});
}

index.html
<p>Hello,</p> <strong>Attachment: </strong><p><?= attachment ?></p>


The question doesn't mention relevant details mentioned on answer comment (I already deleted two). You should ensure to provide all the relevant details from the beginning... and if you get a helpful answer, instead of editing the question providing details that invalidate the answers already provided, you should post a new question.

As I mentioned in the answers that I have deleted, 1. As the form has only one item, there is no need to include a for loop. 2. There is a logic problem related to the nested if's. You might change them or ensure that you assign a default value to template.attachment.

You were right! I have to use the for bc in the src there are more questions but my logic was off. I just needed to assign a default value to template.attachment (with the failure message) and even if there is not attachment provided it will send the email using the failure message. Thank you for your time and assistance @Wicket
